# Is there any way to loop over collection of DOM elements without looping in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to manipulate a collection of DOM elements..

**Here's an Example:**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="items">
  <p class="item">Here's some text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's another text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's some another text</p>
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item")

// This is how I do this vanilla JS way
items.forEach(item => {
  item.style.color = "#333"
})

// I want to achieve something like jQuery where we don't have to use loop

$(".item").css("color", "#333")
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried finding solutions but could not find the best solution.

Comment: What do you think jQuery does under the hood? :)

Comment: `$(".item")` returns a list that `.css()` loops through internally. There is no avoiding loops here, and why would you want to?

Comment: You likely meant `const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item")`

Comment: Already writing the question should have given the answer. No, one can not loop over something whilst avoiding looping. And every implemented solution, which of cause has to be accomplished with VanillaJS, would just abstract the looping task away. The easiest and even in the hight times of jQuery most favorable way for targeting any `document` wide classified `.item` element and applying ui changes to each was to provide a more specific css selector like e.g. `.emphasized .item { color: #333; }` and add the `emphasized` class name to a common root/parent element of all `.item` classified ones

Answer (score 4):

Here is one version that does not use a loop and it is really fast too - I changed the colour to show it works better:

```js
const someStyle = `<style>div.items .item { color: #A33; }</style>`;

document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', someStyle);
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <p class="item">Here's some text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's another text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's some another text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: a nice catch but this sets a global style instead of applying to particular dom elements...

Comment: Ok, added .items in front

Comment: And OP likely wanted to use `const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item")` so no difference there

Answer (score 3):

You can monkey patch the `NodeList` prototype or write an alike function/class/factory without monkey patching (like jQuery for example):

```js
NodeList.prototype.css = function(name, val){
  this.forEach(elem => elem.style[name] = val);
  return this;
};

class DomSet{
  constructor(nodelist){
    this.nodelist = nodelist;
  }
  css(name, val){
    this.nodelist.forEach(elem => elem.style[name] = val);
    return this;    
  }
}

const $ = function(selector){
  return new DomSet(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

document.querySelectorAll('.items .item')
  .css('color', 'red')
  .css('background', 'lightgray');
  
$('.items2 .item')
  .css('color', 'blue')
  .css('background', 'yellow');
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <p class="item">Here's some text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's another text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's some another text</p>
</div>

<div class="items2">
  <p class="item">Here's some text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's another text</p>
  <p class="item">Here's some another text</p>
</div>
```